# why the program doesn't begin with main method

Tags: c#, static, instance, program-entry-point

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {           
            Console.WriteLine("enter main method");
            Console.WriteLine(Foo.X);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
    class Foo
    {
        public static Foo Instance = new Foo();
        public static int X = 3;
        //static Foo()
        //{
        //    Console.WriteLine("static constructor");
        //    Console.WriteLine(X);
        //}
        Foo()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("instance constructor");
        }
    }
```

Why the program begin with the code in Foo, after that, the main method begin execute.

The result is:

instance constructor
enter main method
3

Anyone can help?

Comment: Please add appropriate language tag (`java` ?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Foo has a static variable called Instance.

This static variable is intialized before Main is executed, which causes the constructor Foo() to be called

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! I'm not clear about the order or execution, if I have a static constructor in Foo, why the execution begin with main method?